# Alternatives to Python Wexpect package

Tags: python, windows

I have been trying to do some testing on a CLI that you interact with using keyboard inputs where I need to both read CLI output and write keyboard inputs and you cannot close the interface in-between each command.
In my case the Python package Wexpect was ideal as it allows me to do everything I need to, but because of some issues caused by venv the Wexpect package does not always work.

Have anyone come across an working alternative to Wexpect for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have run into the same issue. I came across pywinpty and it gave me exactly what I was in need of. It works like a charm.